# RVM wrapper for God: ERROR: Binary 'god' not found

Tags: ruby, rvm, god

I'm trying to set up an RVM wrapper for God, but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly. God is in my path, but it claims it can't find the binary. Did I misconfigure something?

```
root@hostname:~# rvm info

ruby-1.9.2-p180:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux hostname 2.6.38-linode31 #1 SMP Mon Mar 21 21:22:33 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.6.0 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p180"
    date:         "2011-02-18"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 revision 30909"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""


root@hostname:~# which god
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/god
root@hostname:~# rvm wrapper @global boot god
ERROR: Binary 'god' not found.
root@hostname:~#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  Because your ruby is ruby-1.9.2-p180, you should create your [wrapper](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/god/) with that instead of with @global:

```
$  rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.2-p180 bootup god
```